# Alter Table in MySQL is using only one core

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to enable all CPU cores for "Alter Table" query?
All other queries use 100% cores available, just "Alter Table" uses only one core.
Here are some my.cnf settings:

```
join_buffer_size = 32M
read_buffer_size = 32M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 32M
tmp_table_size = 1G
max_heap_table_size = 1G
#net_buffer_length = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 32M
key_buffer_size = 32M

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

We're using MySQL server 5.6.33 on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Comment: Let's assume you have multiple cores doing the work - what exactly do you expect multiple cores would do on an I/O intensive task? I mean, you don't really think that  several cores ticking at 3+ gigahertz would make your hard drive run faster, right? If you were the programmer behind it, how would you tell your program to split the work on multiple cores? What exactly would be parallelized? Most performance related issues aren't processor-bound but I/O bound, so throwing more cores at something that can't even be split doesn't make it faster.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf   
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;   after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
lscpu    for specs, including MHZ
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: arti, what is result of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%connect%': and SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%connect%';  Your configuration appears to be requesting more RAM than necessary for your per-connection requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't use more than one core for an `ALTER TABLE`, even in MySQL-8.0.

5.7+ has significant improvements to the time of queries that can be done online.

For background `ALTER TABLE`, use the tools [gh-ost](https://github.com/github/gh-ost) or [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-online-schema-change.html) are usable with 5.6.